# Finding the number of sets $\mathcal{A}$ that satisfy $2^{|\mathcal{A}|} = z|\mathcal{A}|$ for some $z\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is a set whose cardinality satisfies that $1\leq |\mathcal{A}|\leq 999$ elements, and that $2^{|\mathcal{A}|} = z|\mathcal{A}|$ for some $z\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$. How can we find the number of sets $\mathcal{A}$ that satisfy this condition?

$$\begin{align}2^{|\mathcal{A}|} = z|\mathcal{A}|&\iff \ln(2^{|\mathcal{A}|}) = \ln(z|\mathcal{A}|) \\\ &\iff |\mathcal{A}|\ln(2)-\ln(|\mathcal{A}|) = \ln(z) \\\ &\iff z = e^{|\mathcal{A}|\ln(2)-\ln(|\mathcal{A}|)}\end{align}$$

By choosing $|\mathcal{A}| = 2^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$,

$$z|\mathcal{A}| = e^{2^{n}\ln(2)-n\ln(2)}2^n = e^{(2^{n}-n)\ln(2)}2^n = 2^{(2^{n} - n)}2^n = 2^{2^n} = 2^{|\mathcal{A}|}$$

However, I am not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: The condition is equivalent to $|\mathcal A|=$ a power of $2.$

Comment: It's about elementary number theory, not analysis.

Answer (score 1):

$2^{|\mathcal{A}|} = z|\mathcal{A}|$ if and only if $|\mathcal{A}| = 2^{m}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Proof: Suppose that $2^{|\mathcal{A}|} = z|\mathcal{A}|$ for some $z\in\mathbb{Z}_{+}$. Prime factorization theorem, states that every integer greater than 1 can be represented uniquely as a product of prime numbers, we have that the descomposition of $2^{|\mathcal{A}|}= 2\cdot2\cdots2$. the descomposition of  $z = p_{1}\cdots p_{r}$ and the descomposition of $|\mathcal{A}| = q_{1}\cdots q_{\ell}$. Thus we have that $2\cdots 2 = p_{1} \cdots p_{r} \cdot q_{1} \cdots q_{\ell}$ and then $p_{i}$ and $q_{j}$ are equal to $2$ for all $i,j$.

Hence $|\mathcal{A}| = 2^{m}$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

Conversely, if $|\mathcal{A}| = 2^{m}$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$, then we take $z = 2^{2^{m}-m}$ and it follows that $2^{2^{m}} = 2^{|\mathcal{A}|} = 2^{2^{m}-m}2^{m} = z|\mathcal{A}|$.

Answer (score 0):

For $|\mathcal A|\geq |\mathbb N|$, we have that $2^{|\mathcal A|}>|\mathcal A|=z|\mathcal A|\quad (\forall z\in \mathbb Z_+)$.

For $n:=|\mathcal A|$ finite, we have that $\dfrac{2^n}{n}\in \mathbb Z_+$ (it's clear that $n\neq 0$). Hence, $n$ is of the form $2^m$ for $m\in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$. Since both $2^n=2^{2^m}$ and $n=2^m$ are powers of $2$ and $2^n>n$, we have that
$$
n\in \{1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,\ldots \}.
$$